# Format the total value to a currency with 2 decimal places

Tags: database, oracle, sqlplus

A rather simple question. I have to write a query to find the total value of the product inventory.  Display this amount as currency with 2 decimal places.

I know how to get the total value easy enough, and I know of the TO_CHAR use, however when I attempt it I get a FROM error.

```
SELECT SUM(PROD_QOH * PROD_PRICE) AS TotalValue 
FROM BOFF.LGPRODUCT;
```

The outcome is 360307.79.

I'd like for it to display $360,307.79

FORMAT will be an invalid identifier. Have to use TO_CHAR

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, got it myself.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SUM(PROD_QOH * PROD_PRICE), '$999,999.99') AS TotalValue
FROM BOFF.LGPRODUCT;
```

Comment: You would be better off with a format mask of `'$999,990.00'` to ensure that if you have a whole number, you still get the decimals shown, or if you have something less than a dollar that the decimal point is preceded by a 0.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to format it as "Currency", You could use:

```
SELECT FORMAT(SUM(PROD_QOH * PROD_PRICE), 'C', 'en-us')
```

For more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx

Comment: I didn't notice the Oracle tag. I answered for MS SQL Server and put a reference from MSDN.